# Authorization in web api in asp.net MVC

Tags: rest, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

**I am new to ASP.NET and rest...**

I am simply making an web api2 My REST server is ready to go and also Client is ready.

The API must me accessed only by valid user with username and password. So it is required to check the valid user so I tried to access the user by:

```
var uri = 'http://localhost/ProductsApp/api/products/username/password';

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Send an AJAX request
    $.getJSON(uri)
        .done(function (data) {
            // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
            $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                // Add a list item for the product.
                $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#products'));
            });
        });
});
```

And on that call it access the method below:

```
public IEnumerable<Clients> GetAllClients( string username, string password)
{

    //Here i tried to check the username and password

    HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage();
    message.GetClientCertificate();
    return dbContext.Clients.ToList();
}
```

But throws error. And it seems that this is not the method so. Please can you help me referring a good tutorial or solving this issue... It would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A walk through implementing webapi2's default Bearer Authentication can be found [here.](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/authentication/individual-accounts-in-aspnet-web-api)

To register a user you need to post to /api/account/register. The body will include UserName, Password, and ConfirmPassword properties.

```
{
    'UserName': 'neil',
    'Password': 'secretPassword',
    'ConfirmPassword: 'secretPassword'
}
```

And add Content-Type: application/json as a header.

Once you have a registered user, you can log them in by posting to /Token and receiving a token that is used to identify the user. You need to add the following headers to this post:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

And the body will look like:

```
grant_type=password&username=neil&password=secretPassword
```

That post will return a token. You'll need to include the token as a header with following requests. The header looks like:

```
Authorization: bearer xxx *where xxx is the token.*
```